# Is there a shortcut or quick way to show the desktop on Centos 7?

Tags: centos

On windows, you can click on the bottom right corner of the screen(shown in the image below), it's a small vertical button, and regardless of how many programs are opened, pressing this minmizes all the programs, and shows the desktop screen.

On Centos 7, is there something similar to this or a shortcut that will display the Desktop screen because sometimes I will run many programs at once and need to see the actual Desktop screen and right now I have to minimize each and every program that is opened just to see it.

[image]

Comment: This is far more dependent on the desktop environment (DE) you use that on the particular distribution you are running.  If you add that information to your question, you may get better help.  You can also state that you a specific DE is not important to you and that you're just looking for one that has this feature.

Comment: What desktop are you using? Gnome? KDE? MATE?

Comment: I am using gnome-classic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to:

All settings -> Keyboard - > Shortcuts -> Navigation -> Hide all Normal Windows

Click on the disabled area and enter a key combination that you want to use. That will set it and you'll be able to use it to show the desktop/hide all windows.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.